# Spring roo entities - storing long strings

Tags: java, spring-roo

I have to store long strings in MySQL database using spring roo. I assumed that "field string" command generates field with size 255 which is too small. I prefer to not use blob. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the field using a command like `field string --fieldName field1 --sizeMax 500` then Roo will annotate the field with `@Size(max = 500)` and it works for me if I let Hibernate to create the database schema.

(--sizeMax is an optional parameter, you can display all optional parameters after you defined all mandatory ones with -- and hitting TAB)

Another solution is to add manually the JPA annotation on the field: `@Column(length=500)`.
Or if you don't generate the database schema but create it by hand then you can define your column as you like.

Comment: Size work out, I've set high number and it creates LONGTEXT field in database. Thanks.